# How to fix ANONYMOUS LOGON error in Web part SQL Data Connection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net

I have the following SqlConnection String:

```
("Data Source=DataBaseServerName;Initial Catalog="Database Name";Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=30");
```

The database server connects using Windows Authintication. I am getting this NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON error

```
[Exception: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.]
   Test.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +483
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +350
   Test.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1.CreateChildControls() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +61
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394
```

Please Help

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either grant the anonymous user access to SQL (Not recommended) or make use of the `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` feature in SharePoint when calling the database.  Using that will execute the code as the pool account rather than as the user account.

The full details are [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx), just be sure to instantiate your SPSite object inside the code block running with priveleges, otherwise it will still attempt to use the User account.  The last code sample on the page illustrates this.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I noticed that Sharepoint App Pool Identity was a service account which didnt have access to the database. So once the service account got the access to the DB and I ran connection string code block with in SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges. That Worked for me.